# MySQL cluster data node replacement

Tags: mysql, cluster

I have a MySQL cluster with 2 data storage nodes running from last 2 years.

Just recently I have observed a hardware issue in one of the nodes (data storage). I may need to replace this node with new one altogether.

It will be great if someone can suggest the best way to do it. I am trying to prevent any data lose during this process. Will it be ok if I do not use same mysql version as installed in other nodes.

Comment: What is your current mysql version?